# How does one exercise their GDPR related rights?

Tags: privacy, data-ownership, gdpr

In May, [GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/) will become effective and have a global impact on how personal data is handled.

[Article 20](https://gdpr-info.eu/) of the GDPR requires complying systems provide Data Portability.

***If a European citizen was to try and exercise the rights given by this Article for example, how would they go about it?***

Comment: Your previous question suggests that you wanted to ask another question: "The GDPR gives me certain rights, by imposing obligations on companies. One of those rights is the right to access my own data. How do I **exercise that right?**". This is not _enforcement_.

Comment: @MSalters sorry, English isn’t my first language, exercising is the word I was looking for! I will edit

Answer (score 2):

The GDPR is implemented by legislation in each member state - there is no EU wide enforcement.

Individual citizens have no right to take action - they must report it to the regulator who will investigate and take action if they deem it appropriate. The UK regulator is the [Information Commissioner's Office](https://www.gov.uk/data-protection/make-a-complaint).

Comment: Thanks! Where is the list of regulators for each country?

Comment: "The GDPR is implemented by legislation in each member state": no, [it isn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation). It's a Regulation, not a Directive, so it applies to all member states without additional legislation.